# How do I get the panic message in Rust when using #[no_std]?

Tags: rust, rust-no-std

I am writing embedded Rust code that uses `#[no_std]` (with `panic = "abort"`).

I have a custom panic handler like this:

```rust
#[inline(never)]
#[panic_handler]
fn panic(info: &PanicInfo) -> ! {
    let mut serial = open_serial_port();
    if let Some(location) = info.location() {
        uwriteln!(&mut serial, "Panic occurred in file '{}' at line {}", location.file(), location.line());
    } else {
        uwriteln!(&mut serial, "Panic occurred");
    }

    // I want to to get info.payload(), info.message(), info.to_string() or any other way
    // to get some info about why the panic happened

    loop {
        // blink LED
    }
}
```

This works great for showing the location of the panic, but it doesn't show the reason the panic happened.

I've seen a pattern like:

```rust
if let Some(s) = info.payload().downcast_ref::<String>() {
    // print s
}
```

but it seems like I don't have access to `String` in `no_std`. Is there another way to extract that information?

I saw someone recommending that I use a custom payload type that I can print, but I can't figure out how. I don't really care about the `panic!()` macro. I'm more concerned with catching rust's debug checks like arithmetic overflow, etc. Is there a way to tell the compiler how to generate panic payloads for those? I have been looking but haven't been able to find any examples of that.

Comment: Take a look at this custom uart panic writer I wrote: https://github.com/imxrt-rs/imxrt-uart-panic/blob/main/src/lib.rs

Comment: Have you tried `downcast_ref::<str>()`?

Comment: @PitaJ I think the intended way is to use the `Display` impl. The message is internally stored as `fmt::Arguments`, which can only really be processed by a `Write` implementation.

Comment: @PitaJ I have tried `<&str>`. It compiles fine but it just never seems to evaluate true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PanicHandler` implements `Display`. You can use that to print the normal panic message as seen on an `std` target.

This is taken from [`imxrt-uart-panic`](https://github.com/imxrt-rs/imxrt-uart-panic) (disclaimer: I wrote that crate):

```rust
#[panic_handler]
fn panic(info: &::core::panic::PanicInfo) -> ! {
    use ::core::fmt::Write as _;

    /* ... */

    struct UartWriter<P, const N: u8> {
        uart: hal::lpuart::Lpuart<P, N>,
    }
    impl<P, const N: u8> ::core::fmt::Write for UartWriter<P, N> {
        fn write_str(&mut self, s: &str) -> ::core::fmt::Result {
            for &b in s.as_bytes() {
                if b == b'\n' {
                    let _ = block!(self.uart.write(b'\r'));
                }
                let _ = block!(self.uart.write(b));
            }
            Ok(())
        }
    }

    let mut uart = UartWriter { uart };

    ::core::writeln!(uart).ok();
    ::core::writeln!(uart, "{}", info).ok();
    ::core::writeln!(uart).ok();

    let _ = block!(uart.uart.flush());
        
    /* ... */
}
```

The gist is that you create a `struct` that implements `core::fmt::Write`. With it, you can then `core::writeln!()` the error message into whatever peripheral you desire, like UART.

An example of what this would print:

```rust
fn main() -> ! {
    panic!("Foo!");
}
```

```
panicked at examples\minimal.rs:11:5:
Foo!
```

---

Just for reference, if customization is required, this is the [current implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/panic/panic_info.rs.html#160-177) of the `Display` impl of `PanicInfo`: (*Important:* This might change in the future.)

```rust
impl fmt::Display for PanicInfo<'_> {
    fn fmt(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        formatter.write_str("panicked at ")?;
        self.location.fmt(formatter)?;
        if let Some(message) = self.message {
            formatter.write_str(":\n")?;
            formatter.write_fmt(*message)?;
        } else if let Some(payload) = self.payload.downcast_ref::<&'static str>() {
            formatter.write_str(":\n")?;
            formatter.write_str(payload)?;
        }
        // NOTE: we cannot use downcast_ref::<String>() here
        // since String is not available in core!
        // The payload is a String when `std::panic!` is called with multiple arguments,
        // but in that case the message is also available.
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That looks promising. Unfortunately when I try to convert it to the ardiuno nano I get a linker error: `section '.data' is not within region 'data'.` I think that means the compiler pulled in too many strings and I ran out of program memory. It might just not be doable on this hardware

Comment: Oh. That sucks :/ Shouldn't be that many strings though ... very weird. Either way, I hope you find something that works for you :)

Comment: Yeah it's unfortunate. The rust compiler really doesn't optimize for Harvard architecture so even things that should be const and could be stored in the `.text` section get pulled into the `.data` section and then get loaded into RAM. I only have 2kb of RAM to work with so I could maybe believe there are around 2kb worth of strings describing different panic causes that the compiler otherwise optimizes away. IDK why it seems very touchy with the panic handler specifically. I have run into this issue before whenever I try to but some real logic in there. Maybe there is a bug somewhere...